# How to save the spinner selected value in android?

Tags: android, database, spinner

I am trying to save spinner selected value, but i am getting like below i shown when i retrieve the details. Anybody know what is the problem.

```
Spinner:android.widget.Spinner@43e807a0
```

Comment: Show your code how you are saving the Selected Value

Comment: String pres_doctor =   mPres_doctor.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: mPres_doctor.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
       View view, int position, long id) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used the `getSelectedItem()` inside `setOnSelectedListner`? If not, do as shown below:

```
mPres_doctor.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
    String pres_doctor = mPres_doctor.getSelectedItem().toString();

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

The result is displaying as an object value, usually I follow the below method to get the spinner values:

```
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
    this, R.array.spinner, android.R.layout.spinner_layout);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**strings.xml**

```
<string-array name="spinner">
 <item>Dev</item>
 <item>Stieve</item>
 <item>John</item>
 <item>Britto</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: hi das, in my app i am filling the spinner from database not from creating Arrayadapter.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-populate-spinner-widget-from.html,
you may get it,

Comment: @sachi Whether you fill the spinner from database or string-array, that is actually not matter, for your case if you want to fetch values from database and want to display then you just need to change the R.array.spinner while creating ArrayAdapter.

Comment: ya @paresh mayani, i think you understand my problem. can you brief what is the problem i am facing.